# How to change the color of progress indicator in windows phone 7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, progress-bar

I want to change the color of the progress indicator. The default color is Red. If i want to change the color to Blue mean what i have to do. I can not find any property for the indicator color. Is it possible to change the color?

```
<Grid Background="#7F000000" x:Name="ProgressGrid" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible}">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,500,0,0" Height="100" Text="{Binding Path=AppResources.Label558, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Width="383" Margin="0,500,0,0" />
        </Grid>
```

Please let me know any idea..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Change `Foreground` property of progress bar to achieve that :

```
<ProgressBar Foreground="Blue" />
```

Another thing that you missed is, progress bar color is set to phone accent theme by default. You see it Red because phone theme is set to red accent at that moment. And it isn't recommended to change the default behavior, unless you have a good reason to do so.